# sed extract first field and move to specific place

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression

I have this file

```
10.1.1.1    www1           
10.1.1.2    www2           
10.1.1.3    www3
```

I want to extract first `IP address` field and move it following place with `http://www.foo.com=10.1.1.1/test.php`

```
10.1.1.1    www1           # http://www.foo.com=10.1.1.1/test.php
10.1.1.2    www2           # http://www.foo.com=10.1.1.2/test.php
10.1.1.3    www3           # http://www.foo.com=10.1.1.3/test.php
```

I can do this with `for loop` but i want to do it with `sed` with single liner trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed 's@\([^ ]*\)\(.*\)@\1\2 #http://www.foo.com=\1/test.php@'
```

- I used `@` as the delimiter not to have to backslash the slashes in the address.
- The IP address is matched by `[^ ]*`, i.e. non-whitespace at least zero times, and captured by `\(\)` into `\1`. The rest of the line is captured into `\2` by `.*`, i.e. anything.

Comment: Slightly shorter: `sed 's@\([^ ]*\).*@& #http://www.foo.com=\1/test.php@'`

Comment: +1 since the question refers sed and this is a sed solution indeed

Answer (score 4):

a one line awk approach: (I'll delete if you really don't want awk)

> Thanks to RomanPerekhrest for the improvement:

```
awk '{ $3="# http://www.foo.com="$1"/test.php" }1' $file
```

Or if you want/need to keep the tabs in your output:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t";}{ $3="# http://www.foo.com="$1"/test.php" }1' $file
```

Comment: awesomenesssss!!!! awk is amazing too! good to learn

Comment: even shorter `awk '{ $3="# http://www.foo.com="$1"/test.php" }1' file`

Comment: I would `ANSWER` this because you were first, also i like this new awk one liner  :)

Comment: I think choroba should have gotten the answer.  He actually answered before me and he used sed as you had asked.

Comment: I listen to you 